# How to adjust width of a child element without adjusting the width of the parent in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sizer" />
  <div class="child" />
</div>

.sizer {
width: 200px;
}

.child {
position: relative;
width: 400px;
}
```

I am not allowed to explicitly set the width on the parent, and I am not allowed to set the child to `position:absolute`.

Using CSS, is there any other way to set the width of `.child` to 400 without also having the width of `.parent` expand from 200 to 400?

Comment: If you can't set a width on the parent, how does it get its width to begin with?

Comment: Are you asking if the width of the child can exceed the width of the parent?

Comment: @JSW189 -- yes, without setting width on parent and without setting child to position:absolute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the parent has a set width, then it will not expand with the width of the child, even if the child's width exceeds that of the parent. See [this JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xgYEt/1/).

```
.parent {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
}

.child {
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;

}
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

> I am wondering if there is any kind of hack that allows me to do it without setting width on parent

There is no way to accomplish this without the parent having some sort of width or width-like property. If you are only opposed to using the `width` property on the parent, you can use several width-like alternatives.

As cimmanon explained in a comment below, you could set `.parent` to have a `max-width`. It does not necessarily have to be `100%`; any max-width will do, as long as it is less than the width of the child. [See this JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xgYEt/3/), or check out this code:

```
.parent {
    max-width: 200px;
} 

.child {
   width: 400px;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `position:absolute` and set the `left` and `right` properties. [See this JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xgYEt/2/), or check out this code:

```
.parent {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

But remember, these are only two of the many possible alternatives. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am wondering if there is any kind of hack that allows me to do it without setting width on parent

Answer (score 0):

You could set the max-width of the parent to 100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/aFdzy/

```
.parent {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.child {
    width: 400%;
}
```